# Subring generated by the set of all symmetric matrices contains skew-symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, symmetric-matrices, skew-symmetric-matrices

This question is asked in **Topics of Algebra** by **I N Herstein** -
*In $\displaystyle F_{n}$ let $\displaystyle S$ denote the set of all symmetric matrices. Prove that the subring of $\displaystyle F_{n}$ generated by $\displaystyle S$ is all of $\displaystyle F_{n}$*

$\displaystyle F_{n}$ is the set of all $\displaystyle n\times n$ matrices over $\displaystyle F$.

My solution: for all $\displaystyle A$ and $\displaystyle B$ in $\displaystyle S$, $\displaystyle AB$ will be in subring generated by $\displaystyle S$. But $\displaystyle AB$ need not to be symmetric as $\displaystyle AB$ will be symmetric if and only if \ $\displaystyle A$ and $\displaystyle B$ commute. This implies that Subring will contain elements that are not symmetric.

But does this imply that **subring generated by $\displaystyle S$** will contain skew symmetric elements and **will be all of $\displaystyle F_{n}$?**

Comment: No, it does not (yet) imply it. You have to prove more.

Comment: Then how can I prove it?

Comment: You could use a [basis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/853146/is-the-space-of-symmetric-matrices-generated-by-rank-1-matrices) of symmetric matrices.

Comment: Lemm $3.4$ [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjGg_r73JDrAhWNOcAKHRjGAE4QFjAAegQIARAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sciencedirect.com%2Fscience%2Farticle%2Fpii%2FS0024379512006465%2Fpdf%3Fmd5%3D4e9eac18c7955c603bb3b4ec0aa4211a%26pid%3D1-s2.0-S0024379512006465-main.pdf%26_valck%3D1&usg=AOvVaw0GGUStI2yh0qyBnXh80vsB) shows that $M_n(K)$ can be generated by two randomly chosen symmetric matrices!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $F_2$ we have $A=\pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}$ and $B=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}$ are both symmetric; $AB-BA$ is non-trivially skew symmetric.  $F_n$ for $n>2$ works the same way.